# Android Studio: Is it possible to trigger hardware menu button

Tags: android, menu, hardware, android-optionsmenu

I have an android application which kind of like a home screen of the build-in screen on android phone. I can list all the available applications and run them. One thing I don't know how to do is when user run an application from my apps, my application can trigger the hardware menu button to show the current application menus.

Is this possible ? If not, what about doing it if the device was rooted.

Answer (score 0):

In activity use override onKeyDown like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch(keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            doSomething();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```

Comment: I have it working by rooting the device.  I need my device to be rooted then  have to send the KeyCode_Menu along in order to load the menu of the other application

Answer (score 0):

In order to open up the menu from other application apart from the caller application, the device have to be rooted before the code to work.