# react-native - Handling android options menu button click?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm developing an Android-/iOS-App with react-native.

I want to allow my customers to select between options upon clicking the "options menu hardware button" in Android (you know, the button usually at the bottom left of the android devices with 3 lines on top of each other, often triggering a menu in the app providing additional options).

Question: **How can I listen to the options menu button click?**

To clearify, I mean that button:

[image]

I know that the button does not exist under iOS and not under all Android phones and I will have to implement another solution for there, but that does not matter at the moment, as I want the button primarily to provide debugging functionality for my customers/testers (e.g. sending me the state of an erroneous screen).

Strangely, I did not find any resources on google regarding this problem, although I would assume wanting to use hardware buttons in react-native is a common task. Maybe I used the wrong search terms - if someone could link me to better terms describing this problem, I'm thankful as well :D.

Only thing I could find is the BackHandler for handling back-button-clicks.

Comment: It seems that the feature you are looking for has to do something with a "System UI tuner".  Just so you have something to feed your search engine. Good luck!

Comment: @0X0nosugar If you are referring to [UI-Tuner](https://www.androidcentral.com/inside-marshmallow-system-ui-tuner), then unfortunately not; I'm not looking to modify the status bar, I want to utilize the following button: http://pccc.edu/uploads/b9/7d/b97d5589c9bc005a6289d2f9cdc7b04f/01-menubutton.jpg

Comment: Sorry, that's the Menu Button. This seems to exist on older devices only. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40713837/5015207) is useful

Comment: actually in newer devices, long pressing the back button will act as the Menu Button. I think this functionality is reserved by `react native` its self.